# Find the boundary map of CW complex of two 0-cells and one 1-cell

Tags: algebraic-topology

The question is given $I_0 = \mathbb{Z}^2, I_1 = \mathbb{Z}$ and a boundary map $\partial: I_1 \to I_0$ defined by $1 \mapsto (+1, -1)$. Find a CW structure on the unit interval $I$ such that the chain complex is isomorphic to $I_\bullet$. I constructed the CW structure as follows

- $X_0$ consists of two distinct points, then $C^{CW}_0(X) = I_0 = \mathbb{Z}^2$
- $X_1 = I$ with the attaching map attaches two points of $S^0$ to two points of $X_0$, then $C^{CW}_1(X) = I_1 = \mathbb{Z}$

As $X_0 \subseteq X_1$, short exact sequence

$$
    0 \to C_\bullet(X_0) \to C_\bullet(X_1) \to C_\bullet(X_1, X_0) \to 0
$$

Induced long exact sequence
$$
    H_1(X_1) \to H_1(X_1, X_0) \to H_0(X_0) \to H_0(X_1)
$$

As $X_1$ contractible, then $H_1(X_1) = 0$, as $X_1$ has two path-components, $X_0$ has one path-components, then $H_0(X_0) = \mathbb{Z}^2, H_0(X_1) = \mathbb{Z}$. Since $H_1(X_1) = 0$, the connecting homomorphism $\partial: H_1(X_1, X_0) \to H_0(X_0)$ is injective.

On the other hand, on the level of chain, the definition of $\partial$ is as follows:

- pick $[c] \in H_1(X_1, X_0)$ where $c \in C_1(X_1, X_0)$ and $\partial c = 0$
- pick $b \in C_1(X_1)$ such that $b \mapsto c$
- take $\partial b \in C_0(X_1)$
- pick $a \in C_0(X_0)$ such that $a \mapsto \partial b$
- then, $\partial: [c] \mapsto [a]$

I am not sure where the gap in my knowledge is as if I follow the procedure, $\partial b$ is always $0$, then the connecting homomorphism is a zero map that is not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial b$ need not always be $0$. For example, take $b$ to be the chain corresponding to the $1$-cell, and let $c$ be its image in $C_1(X_1, X_0)$. Then $\partial b$ lies in $C_0(X_0)$, so $\partial c = 0$ in $C_1(X_1, X_0)$. Indeed, $H_1(X_1, X_0)$ will be free abelian of rank one, generated by $[c]$, and the connecting homomorphism should take $[c]$ to the homology class determined by the difference of the two $0$-cells.

Comment: thank you the clarification